# Flutter: Delay before next page in my app

Tags: flutter

Hello in my app when I click for the next page it takes one second and shows a white screen and then shows me my desired page why does this happen how to remove this delay, anyone, please??

Comment: I'm afraid you need to share a bit more information about pages with us to be able to find a solution

Comment: yes I will use pdf and use third-party plugin pdf render my pdf size is 70 MB but i will use 5 MB pdf also but the problem was same that load a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your code especially where you write your navigate function to next page and for white screen, there maybe some values which cause this issue. to trace them you can debug or put exception breakpoint in VSCode.

Comment: how can I trace automatically

Comment: You have to put exception breakpoint in VSCode and run your app. If any issue is there than it will display particular line of code which cause this white screen issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some api call during page navigation, it will have some delay to load another page. for that, you have to implement loader, which will notify your users that it is in loading stage. will drop the document link below.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html